# Does same chinese characters shared by cjk share same unicode value?

Tags: unicode, character, cjk

There are almost 808 chinese characters shared by china and japan and korea ,such as `門` (means door in English),the unicode value of chinese `門` is  9580,What about the japanese and korea `門` ?
What are the unicode value of japanese and korea `門` ?
Are they same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not particularly well versed in how Han characters are handled by Unicode, but it would appear that the character is shared. [U+9580](https://codepoints.net/U+9580) sits under the [CJK Unified Ideographs](https://codepoints.net/cjk_unified_ideographs) block. As [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs) describes it:

> The Chinese, Japanese and Korean (CJK) scripts share a common background, collectively known as CJK characters. In the process called Han unification, the common (shared) characters were identified and named "CJK Unified Ideographs". As of Unicode 8.0, Unicode defines a total of 80,388 CJK Unified Ideographs

Under the [Han unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification) effort, one important point to note is:

> Modern Chinese, Japanese and Korean typefaces typically use regional or historical variants of a given Han character.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly yes, but some variant characters are encoded under different code points since they are seen as different characters.